# Trouble getting PolynomialFeatures to work while fitting a logistic model in Scikit Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Kaggle has an introductory data science problem on the Titanic, where the goal is to predict the chances of survival of a passenger, given some information about him/her (eg. sex, age, cabin class etc.). I implemented a simple logistic regression model for this in Python using Scikit Learn, and I was exploring adding higher degree factors of the "Age" variable in particular. I used PolynomialFeatures following the instructions on Scikit Learn's site:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

# Import titanic data
titanic = pd.read_csv("train.csv")

# Set the training set as 70% of the dataset and cross_validation set as remaining 30%
predictors = ["Age"]
training_set = titanic[predictors].iloc[range(0,int(titanic.shape[0]*0.7)),:]
cv_set = titanic[predictors].iloc[range(int(titanic.shape[0]*0.7),titanic.shape[0]),:]
training_actuals = titanic["Survived"].iloc[range(0,int(titanic.shape[0]*0.7))]
cv_actuals = titanic["Survived"].iloc[range(int(titanic.shape[0]*0.7),titanic.shape[0])]

# Create polynomial features
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
training_set = poly.fit_transform(training_set)
cv_set = poly.fit_transform(cv_set)

# Fit a logistic regression model, predict values for training and cross-validation sets
alg = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
alg.fit(training_set, training_actuals)
cv_predictions = alg.predict(cv_set)
training_predictions = alg.predict(training_set)

# Measure and print accuracy of prediction over both training and cross-validation sets
cv_accuracy = len(cv_predictions[cv_predictions == np.array(cv_actuals)])/float(len(cv_predictions))
print "Prediction accuracy on cross-validation set is %s%%" % (cv_accuracy * 100)
training_accuracy = len(training_predictions[training_predictions == np.array(training_actuals)])/float(len(training_predictions))
print "Prediction accuracy on training set is %s%%" % (training_accuracy * 100)
```

My accuracy of predicted values over the training set improves 1-2 percentage points when I add a square feature for the age (i.e. polynomial degree 2), but when I make the degree 3, as in the code above, the accuracy actually reverts to the same as for the linear case (i.e. degree = 1). Theoretically it should improve slightly or stay the same as for degree = 2. This behavior continues for all higher degrees as well. I am very new to Scikit Learn, and I would appreciate any insight on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: "**Theoretically** it should improve ..." -- You mean **intuitively** you believe it should improve. It's important not to confuse the two :)

Answer (score 1):

Accuracy does not have to improve or stay the same when adding more variables. The fact that adding more features is decreasing the model accuracy is speaking about the insignificance of added features.

When a new feature is added to the model, whether it is statistically significant (i.e. "considerable" affects the model outcome) or not, less variation in the model will be observed. Thus, some of the resulting coefficients (e.g. R^2) will increase. However, the model accuracy can drop, as adding insignificant features can negatively affect the significance of existing explanatory variables which are correlated with the new feature.

**Your Example:** When you use the polynomial features, you must always be cautious with higher degrees. For 2nd degree case the accuracy is increased, as the relationship between the outcome and the Age variable turns out to be quadratic. But when you increase the degree to 3, the cubic Age is added, which is an insignificant feature. While it does not improve the accuracy because of being insignificant, it also decreases it, because of being correlated with Age and Age square. The correlation between Age square (significant) and Age cube (insignificant) variables makes Age square also insignificant, thus, dropping the overall predictive power.